# Angular 5 observable getting unsubsribed automatically

Tags: angular, observable

I am using observables for real-time data updations.
Now I had subscribed to that observable from two components, in one component its working fine properly as it is supposed to be but in another component its working and gets unsubscribed maybe because it stops responding/printing values in the console.

When I run the app on different port everything works like a charm but after some time same issues start
can anyone help me with that?

sending data via:-

currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
this.currentMessage.next(data);

Comment: Please provide more code. We don't have an idea how you've implement your subscription

Comment: May be in other componet where you don't see data.. there are some errors.. did you check console? Post the code of that component.

Comment: actually it works sometime but after that stops working in another component and when i changes the port , it works again after sometime stops working
Maybe the issue of cache i think?